# facebook api showing weird "Platform Story Share" when clicking share on a feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm using the javascript sdk to show the FB dialog to post a feed on the user's wall.  this gets posted to the wall fine, but when you click the "share" link in the feed on the wall the "share this story" dialog just displays "Platform Story Share"

i get this even when using the example code from the FB api documentation.

anyone got any ideas why this happening? or alternatively, how to remove the "share" link in the feed

attached is a screenshot 
[image]

e.g from FB docs

```
<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bug has been filed with Facebook about this behavior:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/308745185846464

There isn't a workaround for it.

Comment: it appears that facebook have fixed this bug